Favicon Not Updating in Browser After Logo Change (React Web App Hosted on Hostinger)
I'm working on a React web application hosted on Hostinger. During development, I temporarily added a logo to the favicon and other icons. Recently, I updated the favicon with the new official logo, but the change isn't reflected in the browser's search list or tab icon.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Cleared the browser cache.
Confirmed that the updated favicon file is present in the public folder.
Verified the index.html includes the correct favicon link
Despite these steps, the old logo still shows up in the browser. Is there something I’m missing or need to do differently to ensure the new favicon appears correctly?
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Have you updated manifest.json with the new file?

Open the webpage in an incognito window.
